# Sending data to php script without ajax

Tags: javascript, php

I am required to send data from an html page, via input elements to a php script and I cannot use ajax for some reason. How to accomplish this?

My code is something like this:

HTML:

```
First Name : <input type"text" name="first_name">
<br><br>
Last Name : <input type"text" name="last_name">
<br><br>
<button id="submit_btn">Submit</button>
```

Now, I want the javascript to be something like :

```
function redirect_from_here() {
        close(); //close the current window
        window.location='./phpfile.php'; //load the new page which will process the data sent to it.
}
```

My question is how do I send the value in the input elements in the HTML portion, as data to be processed, to the php script (phpfile.php in this case).

Please note that I prefer not to use html form for doing the job.

Comment: Submit the form...!? There aren't really any alternatives.

Comment: "Please note that I prefer not to use html form for doing the job" — Why? It is the simplest, most reliable way to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: You could inject an image into the DOM which passes data via the GET parameters. e.g. <img src="http://www.example.com/script.php?input=test&another=test"> This is a dirty hack but meets your requirements of not using XHR or a form.

Comment: @FreddieColeman ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 2):

1. You are using HTML form as there are input fields in you code.
2. Inputs are part of a form and should be wrapped by a form element
3. Why using JS for submitting the form when you can use `<form action='script.php'..` for that?

I suggest that you revise your requirements instead of trying to come up with a hackish way of how to send the data..

Answer (score 0):

Just submit a form with `action="phpfile.php"`

if not interested with html,
then in the window location bind the values as a GET form method do

Comment: I have regarded the suggestions and tried the following     in the script: phpfile.php                            <script type="text/javascript">
   
   

     function goback() { 
     window.history.back(1);
    };
    

  </script>

 <?php

  $name = $_POST['fname'];

  echo "$name";


 ?>
 
 <br><br><br><br>

 <button id="back_btn" onclick="goback()">Back</button>  with error from php - Undefined index: fname. Any help? Forgot to write that I actually used fname as the name attribute of one attribute